# PHP MySQL WHERE cell is blank not returning information

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a script to insert values into a database and then once done passes a header to a page where it checks for blank values in a certain column and returns them on the page which I will later make editable so they can be updated.

The problem I'm having is when I'm running the query its not returning the cells with the blank values.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `team`=''";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if(!$result) {
    echo "Cannot do query" . "<br/>";
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];

$each_results = mysql_fetch_row($result);

for ($i=0; $i<$each_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
    echo $row['rep_num'] . " " ;
    echo $row['team'] . " ";
    echo $row['description'] . "</br>";
}
```

I tried SELECT * FROM `data` and it returned all the results including the results with no team value. I ran the SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `team`='' query in phpmyadmin and it did return the rows I expected it to with the missing cell data from the team row. So I guess its something wrong with my for loop at the bottom.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: Are you sure they are blank? NULLS are not blanks and should be treated different

Comment: also, you can use length but as said above and below if you have nulls the length function will return another null.
PS: NULLS are a mess if one doesn't know how to deal with them :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$each_result` does not contain the value you expect it to; you have fetched a row from the result set into it as an array, and cannot do a comparison like `$i < $each_results`) Rather than a `for` loop, iterate your rows with a `while` loop

```
// Don't call fetch here, as it will advance the record pointer
// before you intend to.
//$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
//$count = $row[0];

//$each_results = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Replace the for loop with a while loop
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['rep_num'] . " " ;
    // Note, team should be blank because you queried team=''
    echo $row['team'] . " ";
    echo $row['description'] . "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have NULL and ot blank field, use 'IS NULL' or 'IS NOT NULL' or the isnull() mysql function